# Implementing Regex in AppleScript for matching exactly 6 numbers

Tags: regex, applescript

I am new to Regex and AppleScript and I need a little bit of support and guidence.

First user inputs a string. It could be anything in one or multilines.

A Regex should be applied on the string in order to find numbers with only 6 digits..no more or less, and separates them by a space.

The final string should look like: `867689, 867617, 866478, 866403, 866343`.

Then this string will be converted into a list.
I am using this site to test my Regexes : https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

The Regex that matches exactly 6 digits is:
`(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)`
I am aware that in order to implement Regex to AppleScript i need to use Shell Script. I also am aware that I should use `sed` but unfortunately I am not fully aware how to use it and what exactly is.

Fallowing a few guides and tests I understood that sed does not work with `\d` and I should use `[0-9]` instead and I also should escape the brackets like this `\(..\)`. Also replace `$1,` should be implemented like `\1,`. Till this moment I was not able to make it work.

My user input for tests is as follows:

```
MASTER
ARTIKEL
Artikel
5910020015
867689
PULL1/1
5910020022
867617
PULL1/1
Cappuccino
5910020017
866478
PULL1/1
Braun
5921020017
866403
SHIRT1/2
Kastanie-Multi
5910020016
866343
PULL1/1
```

**and the AppleScript Code itself:**

```
use scripting additions
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use framework "Foundation"

on list2string(theFoldersList, theDelimiter)
    set theBackup to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theString to theFoldersList as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theBackup
    
    return theString
    
end list2string
on run {input}
    display dialog "Please enter your string: " default answer ""
    set stringOfNumbers to the text returned of the result
    
    set num to do shell script "sed 's/\(\(?<![0-9]\)[0-9]{6}\(?![0-9]\)\)\1, /' <<< " & quoted form of stringOfNumbers 
    --(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
    display dialog stringOfNumbers

    set stringOfNumbers to current application's NSString's stringWithString:stringOfNumbers
    set listOfArtNumbers to (stringOfNumbers's componentsSeparatedByString:", ") as list
    display dialog list2string(listOfArtNumbers, ", ")
    return input
    
end run
```

Unfortunately everywhere I escape characters by using `\` I get an error. So I had to remove all `\` but once I run the script I receive `"Syntax Error: sed: 1: "s/(?<![0-9])[0-9]{6}(?! ...": unterminated substitute pattern"` and all my effort resulted in a similar error.

Comment: If you are looking for exactly 6 digits and also that is your start and end of string...then you could just use `^[0-9]{6}$` this right ?

Comment: _"I am aware that in order to implement Regex i need to use Shell Script. I also am aware that I should use sed"_. How did you become aware of these two nuggets of wisdom ?

Comment: Backslashes are also used by AppleScript as an escape character in string literals, so must be escaped twice: `"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)"`. AppleScript’s text manipulation capabilities are notoriously awful, but `do shell script`+sed is obsolete advice; use `NSString` + `NSRegularExpression` via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. I wrote an (unsupported) [AppleScript library](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) that provides a native wrapper around it, and there are others (though I can’t comment on the quality of those).

Comment: There's an AppleScriptObjC solution to this, but I'm not sure if you interested. It requires OS 10.7, minimum. Let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: @foo I tried escaping them twise but the result was still the same. Can't be executed properly cause of a sintax error. At the bottom of the post is updated/edited version. Any suggestestions where am i mistaken ?

Comment: @rootkonda Thank you. I will use your Regex since it's shorter.

Comment: @TedWrigley Yes, please. Post it.

Comment: @OutOfTouch - You are welcome. I will post it as answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript Objective-C allows us to do regular expressions using `NSRegularExpression`, starting with OS 10.7 (Lion).  The following handler returns the results of a regular expressions search as a list:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"

property NSRegularExpression : class "NSRegularExpression"
property NSString : class "NSString"

on findPattern:thePattern inString:theString
    set theText to NSString's stringWithString:theString
    set theRegEx to NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:thePattern ¬
        options:0 |error|:(missing value)
    set theResult to (theRegEx's matchesInString:theText ¬
        options:0 ¬
        range:{location:0, |length|:theText's |length|})'s valueForKey:("range")
    
    set outputArray to {}
    repeat with thisRange in theResult
        copy (theText's substringWithRange:thisRange) as text to end of outputArray
    end repeat
    return outputArray
end findPattern:inString:
```

Note that the '¬' symbol is a line-continuation symbol (type option-return in the AppleScript editor). I've broken up lines to make the script more readable, but that may not copy/paste correctly, so be aware that those should be single, continuous lines.

You use this handler as follows. Remember that the backslash is a special character in AppleScript, so it has to be escaped by preceding it with another backslash:

```
set foundList to my findPattern:"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)" inString:"MASTER
ARTIKEL
Artikel
5910020015
867689
PULL1/1
5910020022
867617
PULL1/1
Cappuccino
5910020017
866478
PULL1/1
Braun
5921020017
866403
SHIRT1/2
Kastanie-Multi
5910020016
866343
PULL1/1"

-- Result: {"867689", "867617", "866478", "866403", "866343"}
```

---

***EDIT***

It seems Automator doesn't like the `property ClassName : class "ClassName"` method I've used, so we have to switch to another form: using `current application's ClassName's ...` The revised Automator AppleScript looks like so (assuming that the text string is passed in as the input):

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "Foundation"

on run {input, parameters}
    set foundList to my findPattern:"(?<!\\d)\\d{6}(?!\\d)" inString:((item 1 of input) as text)
    return foundList
end run

on findPattern:thePattern inString:theString
    set theText to current application's NSString's stringWithString:theString
    set theRegEx to current application's NSRegularExpression's regularExpressionWithPattern:thePattern ¬
        options:0 |error|:(missing value)
    set theResult to (theRegEx's matchesInString:theText ¬
        options:0 ¬
        range:{location:0, |length|:theText's |length|})'s valueForKey:("range")
    
    set outputArray to {}
    repeat with thisRange in theResult
        copy (theText's substringWithRange:thisRange) as text to end of outputArray
    end repeat
    return outputArray
end findPattern:inString:
```

Comment: Fallowing your guides i've managed to run it using the mac Script Editor without any problem. Thank you very much :) ! However for some reason i can't run it using Automator. The error i got is Syntax Error Invalid key form. and the code class "NSRegularExpression" have been highlighted. Since this code will be a part of a lot longer script i really need to have in Automator to be able to execute it with just one click. The other option i to just make my already made Script Editor file somehow executable and start it using Automator. Have no idea how to do this. – written by OutOfTouch

Comment: @OutOfTouch: Apparently Automator doesn't like the property method I use to create class references. So kill the property references and use the other reference form: current application's NSRegularExpression's. I'll update my answer – written by Ted Wrigley

Comment: @TedWrigley I've tried the updated version to run in Automator but unfortunately i receive an error that i don't know what might be causing it. Would you please check it..i put the details in my original post EDIT section. Thank you !

Comment: @OutOfTouch: If you're going to use Automator, *use Automator*. Go back to the original script I wrote, and then put the `Ask For Text` Automator action in before it. The Automator action will get the text from the user, and pass it on to the `Run AppleScript` action. Or if you really need to use Applescript's `Display Dialog`, add in a different `Run AppleScript` to run the DD command, then pass the results on to the AS action with the script I provided. Think 'modular'; that's how automator works. Don't try to do too much in any one action.

Comment: @TedWrigley I tried both suggestions.. using Ask for Text Action and moving DD into another Run AppleScript but unfortunatelly the result is still the same error. I can see that "input" is passed from the one AppleScript to the other .. but then something happens and returns this error. I put another Edit to my original post with pictures. But you are right ofcourse. I started learning applescript a few weeks ago just by coding in Automator ... changing a script my friend made. Actions and modular thinking are things that i lack definitely and i am looking to improve.

Comment: @OutOfTouch: I tested it using the script I wrote (unmodified) preceded by an `Ask For Text` Automator action, and it works as expected, without error. Are you still getting the same error you noted before? make sure you've removed the `use scripting additions` line, which I know doesn't play well with Automator.

Comment: @TedWrigley Well. Indeed the script works just fine if used originally ( means with  ¬ sign ). My mistake was to remove  ¬ and make single, continuous lines. Everything is alright now. :) Thanks for guiding me even further in this. A lot leasons learned !